# download video from path save in mysql using php

Tags: php, mysql

I am using directory path that i save in database. how can i download from path. my code is.

```
        if(isset($_POST['download'])) {

        $id = $_GET['id'];
        $query = "SELECT url_video FROM website WHERE id = '$id'"; 
        $result = mysql_query($query); $rowss = mysql_fetch_assoc($query); 
        $name2 = $rowss['url_video'];

        header("Accept-Ranges: bytes"); 
        header("Keep-Alive: timeout=15, max=100");
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.$name2);
        header("Content-type: video/mp4"); 
              //header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");   
        header( "Content-Description: File Transfer");

        exit;        
    }

?>
```

Comment: http://php.net/readfile

Comment: This looks terrifyingly insecure because your user parameters are not [properly escaped](http://bobby-tables.com/php). You should **NEVER** be putting `$_GET` data directly into the query. This creates a gigantic [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). Also, `mysql_query` is an obsolete interface and should not be used, it's being removed from PHP. A modern replacement like [PDO is not hard to learn](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/). A guide like [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) explains best practices.

Answer (score 1):

You need to output/echo the content of the file after you set the download headers.

Also the following

```
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.$name2);
```

should be

```
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.$file_name_not_full_path);
```

or

```
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=downloadedvideo.mpg');
```

Full code (i assume you have a column named `video_path` that stores the path to the file on the server:

```
if(isset($_POST['download'])) {

    $id = $_GET['id']; 
    query = "SELECT url_video, video_path FROM website WHERE id = '$id'"; 
    $result = mysql_query($query); 
    $rowss = mysql_fetch_assoc($query); 

    header("Accept-Ranges: bytes"); 
    header("Keep-Alive: timeout=15, max=100"); 
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.$rowss['url_video']);
    header("Content-type: video/mp4"); 
    header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary"); 
    header( "Content-Description: File Transfer");

    readfile($rowss['video_path']);
}
```

New code version after last comments:

```
if(isset($_POST['download'])) {

    $id = $_GET['id']; 
    query = "SELECT url_video FROM website WHERE id = '$id'"; 
    $result = mysql_query($query); 
    $rowss = mysql_fetch_assoc($query); 

    header("Location: ".$rowss['url_video']);
    exit();
}
```

Comment: sir, please tell me how i can. i am new in this field. please help me sir.

Comment: sir i try this code but i m not able to download my video. after click the download button, i got only 1.3kb file. but original video size is 1.47mb.

Comment: this is my database structure 
id   =     int(11);
image    =    blob;
image_name   =   varchar(255);
url_video blob
video_name varchar(255)

Comment: Are you storing the video in the `url_video` blob column?

Comment: yes sir i store the path in url_video. 
my path is like = [BLOB - 47 B] because this is blod.
i also try to convert varchar(255) then my path appear like this = http://localhost:2120/videos/video/LOL......mp4

Comment: sir really sorry for my bad english. but i hope u understand my problem sir.

Comment: Then instead of all those `header` calls just write this: `header('Location: '.$rowss['url_video']);`

Comment: sir code not working. i have a mistake but i dont know where.

Comment: i try this code. 

<?php


if(isset($_POST['download']))
{



    $id = $_GET['id']; 
    $query = "SELECT video_name,url_video FROM website WHERE id = '$id'"; 
    $result = mysql_query($query); 
    $rowss = mysql_fetch_assoc($query); 

    header("Accept-Ranges: bytes"); 
    header("Keep-Alive: timeout=15, max=100"); 

    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.$rowss['url_video']);
    header("Content-type: video/mp4"); 
    header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary"); 
    header( "Content-Description: File Transfer");

 header('Location: '.$rowss['url_video']);
}
?>

Comment: sorry sir i dont understand

Comment: sir your last code i try. video not downloading. but video start directly on new window. i want download this video. sir please tell me where my mistake.